# How to do this step in react native

Tags: react-native, npm

try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

Comment: You have to run all this command in your terminal with your current project directory.

Comment: 1st one can i use like watchman watch-del-all

Comment: yes. Run that all command.

Comment: PS E:\Native APP\ChatUp>  watchman watch-del-all
watchman : The term 'watchman' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+  watchman watch-del-all
+  ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (watchman:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: when i run 1st command have to face this trouble